# Unable to resolve drawable in attribute "src"

Tags: android, xml, button, imagebutton, src

I'm having a problem when trying to load various images to an image button using an xml file in the drawable-mdpi folder.  It worked for one button but doesn't work for the other.  The code works for the second image button but not the first, I get the error,

> " main.xml: Unable to resolve drawable
>   "C:...workspace\AndroidAlarm\res\drawable-mdpi\keyEntry.xml" in
>   attribute "src".

I did the exact same thing in the first imageButton that I did for the second.  The xml file for the second button (working one) looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_pressed="true"
       android:drawable="@drawable/events_pressed" /> <!-- pressed -->
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/events" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

and for the one that doesn't work, it looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_pressed="true"
       android:drawable="@drawable/key_entry_pressed" /> <!-- pressed -->
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/key_entry" /> <!-- default -->
 </selector>
```

The only difference between the two is the images being passed in.  All the images are found in the drawabl-mdpi folder.  I can't figure out why it works for the second image button but not the first.  the xml code for the two buttons looks like:

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imagebutton1"
                android:src="@drawable/keyEntry"
                android:background = "@android:color/transparent"               
                android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
                android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
                android:scaleType = "fitXY"
                android:layout_marginTop = "50px"
                android:layout_marginLeft = "40px"
                android:layout_marginRight = "20px"
                android:layout_marginBottom = "50px"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <ImageButton 
                android:layout_marginTop="50px"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="40px"
                android:id="@+id/imagebutton2"
                android:layout_weight="1" 
                android:src="@drawable/events" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:background="@android:color/transparent" 
                android:layout_marginLeft="20px" 
                android:layout_marginBottom="50px" 
                android:scaleType="fitXY">
             </ImageButton>
         </LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Resources can not contain capital letters:

```
    android:src="@drawable/keyEntry"
```

You should have error complaining about resource name:

```
    Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
```